Drupal upgrade from 9.5 to 10
I am trying to upgrade drupal 9.5 to 10 but i am a little bit confused so i wanted some suggestion from here.

currently drupal 9.5 is using php version 7.4 so do i need to upgrade php version and mysql db first or do i need to upgrade upgradable modules in drupal first ?
some modules will not upgrade as drupal 10 supporting module require php version 8.
some modules do not have upgrades and do not support durpal 10. is there any way around?

Hoping for some suggestion from the community.

For #1, my recommendation is to upgrade to the highest version of PHP that 9.5 supports, then test and fix any bugs. Next, upgrade Drupal to 10.0, test and fix any bugs.  Then upgrade PHP to the highest version, then Drupal. Go in that order. For #3, no, there's no way around it. Some of these have been folded into core, some were replaced by other modules, some had grand plans to "do something cool" in the next version but didn't, and some were abandoned.

There is a module, https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status, that greatly assists in preparing for an upgrade. The general algorithm is as follows:

Update modules and core to the latest versions supported by your current PHP version.
Upgrade PHP to at least version 8.1.
Check and correct deprecated code in custom modules, if any; upgrade_status or Rector can help with this.
Again, update contributed modules to the latest possible versions.
Identify the list of modules that are not supported by Drupal 10 (this can be done using upgrade_status).
Install the plugin mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient (https://github.com/mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient)—it helps install modules not supported by Drupal 10.
Add unsupported modules to extra.drupal-lenient.allowed-list (e.g., composer config --merge --json extra.drupal-lenient.allowed-list '["drupal/token"]').
Check on drupal.org for patches for unsupported modules that are compatible with Drupal 10 (e.g., Drupal 10 compatibility of Automated Drupal 10 compatibility) and add them or write your own patches.
Update the core to Drupal 10.


Hi @TarasMotuschuk, please see this drupal issue reference where i have explained in detail my remaining issue with this upgrade
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2024-05-01/upgrading-drupal-95-to-1025-issues

You may need to first upgrade your PHP to 8.2, and your MySQL Version to 8.3 so the upgrade will proceed to Drupal 10.
Prior to upgrading to 10, make sure all your modules are upgraded first to their maximum version. This is usually done quickly if your site is using composer (just run composer update, which will upgrade Drupal core and all modules alongside it. You can also see this documentation about this)
Once your modules are updated, you can then proceed to bump your Drupal Version to 10.
As for the modules only supporting 10, you may need to wait for the developer of the said modules to write a Drupal 10 supported version of the modules, or if they are no longer updating said modules, you may need to remove them from your site.
This support thread from Drupal forums may also help you as this has a similar problem with the module support.
